# How to insert the array object into json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wanna ask how to insert empty json with a new data, well I have code like this :

**my_data.json**

```
{
  "data-statement": []
}
```

**javascript (jquery)**

```
//I will made a short code from my all code
const getJSON = "../js/my-file/my_data.json";
$.getJSON(getJSON, function (data) {
   let dataJSON = {
      "statement_name": statementValue,// statementValue is a value of my array
      "statement_condition": selectValue,// selectValue is a value of my array
   }
   data['data-statement'].push(dataJSON);
});
```

The error is not showing anymore, and I think make it works, but when I see into my `json` file my data is not inserted, but why? I expect `my_data.json` will be like this after pushing with new data :

```
{
  "data-statement": [
     {
       "statement_name": statementValue1,
       "statement_condition": selectValue1,
     },
     {
       "statement_name": statementValue2,
       "statement_condition": selectValue2,
     },
  ]
}
```

**I already edit my question and I wanna ask why my data in json is not inserted?**

Comment: ``data`` should be an array, so that you can use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which is an array function on it.

Comment: well I make a some fault in typo sir, I will edit my question and change the question

Comment: `data["data-statement"].push(...)`

Comment: The entity you are pushing to is Object i.e. your JSON root. You need to access `data-statement` instead. `data["data-statement"].push(...)`

Comment: yups, I'm sorry for my typo and I realize if I made some typo and I already edit my question, I don't know why my json file is not inserted by my new data